How to get and pass selected id to modal?
I'm new to python/flask and I have a table with users in it that contains a delete button next to each user in the table. How do I get the userId of the selected user, so that I can pass it to my confirmation modal for deletion?
Here's a snippet of what I currently have and tried, but the set isn't working like I thought it would.
<table class="table align-middle table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-dark">
                                <th>Action</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                            {% for admin in admin_users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td id="action">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>{% set admin_id = admin.id %} {{ admin.username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ admin.email }}</td>                            
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <form action="{{ url_for('delete_user', user_id=admin_id) }}" method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete">
                        </form>
                    </div>

